# How to draw bold fonts with richtext_grob?

Tags: r

I tried to draw bold fonts with richtext_grob in different ways, but nothing seems to work.

Here is my code:

```
library(gridtext)
library(grid)

text1 <- "Some text NOT in bold"
text2 <- "Some text **in bold**"
text3 <- c(paste0("<p style='font-weight:bold;'>\n",
                  "Some text in bold",
                  "</p>\n"))
text4 <- "<span style='font-weight:bold;'>Some text in bold</span>"

g <- richtext_grob(text = c(text1, text2, text3, text4), 
                   x = c(0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5), 
                   y = c(0.9, 0.8, 0.7, 0.6))

grid.newpage()

grid.draw(g)
```

Here is my output:
[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AhYsX.png)
I created the output by clicking "Export -> Save as Image..." in the Plots Window.

Here are the results from sessionInfo():

```
R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.utf8  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.utf8    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] gridtext_0.1.4

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.10     digest_0.6.29   magrittr_2.0.3  evaluate_0.15   stringi_1.7.6   rlang_1.0.6    
 [7] cli_3.6.0       rstudioapi_0.13 xml2_1.3.3      rmarkdown_2.14  tools_4.2.2     stringr_1.4.0  
[13] markdown_1.1    xfun_0.31       yaml_2.3.5      fastmap_1.1.0   compiler_4.2.2  htmltools_0.5.5
[19] knitr_1.39
```

My goal is to layout a pdf title page, where I have to use different colors, sizes, fonttypes, text alignments etc.. So it would be great to be able to use HTML tags.

Comment: It doesn't look like `gridtext` supports the `font-weight` CSS tag. It looks like onyl supports [color, font-family, and font-size](https://github.com/wilkelab/gridtext/blob/09d71ab703771f58cb87ccaf16f0871e221b94de/R/drawing-context.R#L38). For me the `**` method works for bolding. I'm not sure what output device you are using but when I run the code and view the result in the RStudio Plot panel, I can see the second text has bolded elements.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that the method I chose works for other users. That makes it even more confusing. Could a wrong installed package be the problem or pc setup in general?

Comment: What version of R are you using? How are you saving the results of the plot? Are you using RStudio or the base R GUI? Edit your question to include the results of `sessionInfo()` so we can see the versions of all the packages loaded when you run the code.

Comment: I'm using RStudio.